I'm having trouble reading the Kanji here
I'm trying to guess which Kanji this is.  Can anyone help? My best guess so far is 宝閉茶呟湾 but that seems incorrect.

My guess would be 室閑茶味清.

Correct. But do note for the future, we don't do transcription or translation requests here.

If you can see https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13167528023 . It seems to be a zen phrase literally meaning room (is) clam (and) tea's taste (is) clean.
